# Harmony os Cannot find StaticSubscriberExtensionAbility

Tags: harmonyos

Cannot find the StaticSubscriberExtensionAbility on harmony os develop process

mode:Stage
Sdk:api 10
Ide :DevEco Studio 4.0.0 Release

[cannot find the StaticSubscriberExtentionAbility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNOTh.png)

I have been try api 9 ,it still has this problem.